# Does Apollo store data in cache after failed Query / Mutation and how can I access it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo

I have a simple form that calls a Graphql mutation via Apollo. If it fails, does it store the form data in the apollo cache by default or do I need to explicitly store it?

How can I retrieve the cached data?

My form is like so:

```
const MyForm = () => {

  // Some apollo hook to fetch cached data here?
  
  const [doMutation, { data, error, loading }] = useManagedMutation(MUTATION)

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const firstName = document.getElementById("firstName")
    await mutation({
      variables: firstName
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"/>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default CreateVoucher
```

Comment: cache is for responses (or global app data), not for form data (use formik or at least local state - useState - see react docs)  ... failed > unusable ...